# Taking a range out of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

I have an array with different numbers called wave_data. It has 101 numbers from 0.30000001 to 0.60000002.

This is the code I have:

```
center_wave = 450e-9
width = 50e-9
wavelengths = wave_data*1e-6

range = width/2
min = center_wave - range
max = center_wave + range

wavelengths = wavelengths[somevariable:somevariable]
```

The goal is to have the those two numbers, the min and max variables, be the range for selecting the numbers out of the array. However, I am stuck at this point and do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Select by boolean mask](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), not by slicing:

```
waverange = width/2
wavemin = center_wave - waverange
wavemax = center_wave + waverange
mask = (wavelengths > wavemin) & (wavelengths <= wavemax)
wavelengths = wavelengths[mask]
```

Tip: don't name variables `range`, `min`, or `max` since this shadows Python builtins of the same name.

Comment: that tip is kinda important !

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with a simple list comprehension.

```
center_wave = 450e-9
width = 50e-9
wavelengths = wave_data*1e-6

wave_range = width/2
wave_min = center_wave - wave_range
wave_max = center_wave + wave_range

wavelengths = [x for x in wavelengths if x >= wave_min and x <= wave_max]
```